# Regular Expression - String that contains at most one pair of consecutive 1's

Tags: regex, unix

How to express a string that contains at most one pair of consecutive 1's in **UNIX regex?**

Some examples to accepted strings: 0, 1, 11, 12, 22, 11221212, 22112121, 23456 etc.
Not accepted ones: 111, 11311, 311311 etc.

Comment: share inputs and expected outputs

Comment: The regex language which is used in UNIX/Linux. An example: http://www.thelinuxlink.net/lvlinux/resources/presentations/regexp/regexp.pdf

Comment: @merlin2011 A reasonable interpretation of "UNIX Regex" is that it is the regular expression syntax described by the IEEE 1003.1 standard, a.k.a. POSIX a.k.a. The Single Unix Specification. Click [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), then pick Chapter 9 in the left lower pane.  This leaves open the question of whether it is to be "BRE" or "ERE" regex.

Comment: @Kaz, Thanks for the clarification. I had not been aware that there was regex specific to the OS rather than a specific tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^([^1]+|1[^1])*(11)?([^1]|$)([^1]+|1[^1]|1$)*$
```

See it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lO8wP4/3).

Explanation:

```
([^1]+|1[^1])*
```

This will match anything that doesn't contain consecutive 1, by matching either anything that doesn't contain a 1 or a 1 followed by something else.

```
(11)?([^1]|$)
```

This next part will match two consecutive 1 (if present) followed by either a different char or the end of the string. So it will match a pair of 1 not followed by another 1.

```
([^1]+|1[^1]|1$)*
```

The final part is very similar to the first one, except it will allow the string to end with a single 1.

---

This pattern would be much simpler if you could use a richer regex dialect (like the Perl dialect). In the *standard* unix regexes, you can't use lookaround expressions. Here's a Perl pattern:

```
^(?!.*111)(?!.*11.*11).*$
```

Comment: It seems like you need to address the situation where you might end in a 1 as in 1121. So, maybe `^([^1]+|1[^1])*(11)?([^1]|$)([^1]+|1[^1]|1$)*$`

Comment: @MattCremeens If I understood correctly, OP wants to allow single `1` digits in his input string. He mentions `22112121` as a valid input, so `1121` should be valid too.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski , I agree, `1121` would be valid. That is why I provided the modification. If I'm not mistaken, your regex doesn't match `1121`. A most excellent solution you provided, I just thought it omitted this one instance.

Comment: I just checked on regex101, and it showed me it matches `1121` but I guess it's misleading. It seems `1[^1]` matches `1\n`, and the whole thing won't match if there's no newline. I included your suggestion, thanks! Good spot.

Comment: And guys, an explanation of the pattern would be nice, I'm having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: @Ferit Sure, I've added an explanation, hopefully it'll be helpful.